# Make Kibana field clickable

Tags: visualization, kibana

I have `buildNumber` filed (type is integer) as X-Axis in Kibana 6 visualisation, it looks like this:
[image]

How can I make it clickable? 
E.g. if I click on #5 I'd like to get to event's data:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get what you want by creating a dashboard with:

1. The graph you show above
2. The saved search you display in the picture above (without filtering). First 
   save the search you want and then add it to the dashboard. From ES forum [How 
   to Visualize Discover data in dashboard](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-visualize-discover-data-in-dashboard/52307)

   > When you add a visualization to a dashboard, there are two tabs: one for a list of visualizations and one that shows available saved searches.

When you click the buildNumber a filter will be automatically added to the dashboard which will filter all the items on the dashboard, so you'll see the buildNumber details as you want.